# SQL SELECT query statement

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, select, join

These are the created tables I am working with:

```
create table Customer2 (
    cid char(3), cname char(10), primary key (Cid)
);
create table Employee2 (
    eid char(3), ename char(10), salary number(7,2), mid char(3),primary key (eid), foreign key (mid) references Employee2
);
create table ArtObject2 (
    aoid char(3), atitle char(12), artist varchar(10), pricea number(8,2), primary key (aoid)
);
create table MakesD2 (
    aoid char(3), eid char(3), cid char(3), prices number, dates date, primary key (aoid,CID), foreign key (aoid) references ArtObject2, foreign key (CID) references Customer2, foreign key (eid) references Employee2
);
```

I need to write the following SQL statements:

1. List the names of customers who didn't buy any painting with the asking price 
   higher than $500,000.00
2. Find the names of customers who bought the highest number of paintings
3. For each painting sold display title of the painting, the price paid by a customer 
   and the words "Higher than average" if the painting was sold on the price grater than average asking price and the words "Lower than average" if the painting was sold on the 
   price less than average asking price. For the column holding the words "Higher than 
   asking" or "Lower than asking" make a header Remark.

I tried this statement for #1 but did returned too many results:

```
select cname from customer2 
where cid in (select cid from makesd2 
     where aoid in (select aoid from artobject2 
           where pricea <= '500000'));
```

I tried this statement for #2 but did not return the results:

```
select c.cname from customer2 c 
inner join(select cid, count(*) as bought 
    from makesd2 
    group by cid m on m.cid = c.cid 
    order by m.bought;
```

I tried this statement for #3 and it worked, its just missing the first result which should be 'Spring':

```
select a.atitle, m.prices, 'Higher than average' as "Price" from artobject2 a 
  join makesd2 m on
    a.aoid = m.aoid
    and a.pricea > (select avg(pricea) from artobject2)
union
select a.atitle, m.prices, 'Lower than average' as "Price" from artobject2 a 
  join makesd2 m on
    a.aoid = m.aoid
    and a.pricea <= (select avg(pricea) from artobject2);
```

Comment: No offense, but can we all agree this title is terrible? I have no idea how to fix it, of course.

Comment: Change to "Please do my homework assignment for me."

Comment: Foe #3, you said "if the painting was sold on the price grater than average asking price...". Is the average price across the entire ArtObject2 table??

Answer (score 0):

**Live Demo** of all 3 Queries here => http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/5b3b9/6
If you populate the left section in the fiddle with your data, you can see results right there!

Here are the SQL statements with explanation.

**SQL Query for #1**

```
SELECT C.* 
FROM Customer2 C
LEFT JOIN MakesD2 M ON C.cid = M.cid
INNER JOIN ArtObject2 A ON A.aoid = M.aoid
WHERE A.pricea >= 500000
AND M.cid IS NULL
```

**Explanation of #1 Sql**: You do a LEFT JOIN with MakesD2 so it returns ALL Customers from Customer2 and if they did not have a sale, then the cid in MakesD2 will be NULL for the Condition that pricea in ArtObject2 is more than 500,000

**SQL Query for #2**

```
SELECT c.cname AS 'Customer Name', COUNT(*) AS 'Purchases'
FROM Customer2 C
INNER JOIN MakesD2 M ON C.cid = M.cid
INNER JOIN ArtObject2 A ON A.aoid = M.aoid
GROUP BY c.cname ORDER BY 2 DESC;
```

**Explanation of #2 Sql** You do INNER JOIN (i.e. EQUI JOIN) between Customer,2 MakesD2 and ArtObject2 and GROUP BY Cname and calculate COUNT(*) which will be number of Purchases, and then order it DESC, so the most purchases will be on TOP. If you want only top 5, use `SELECT TOP 5` in the SQL `SELECT`.

**SQL Query for #3**

```
DECLARE @AveragePrice NUMERIC(8,2)
SELECT @AveragePrice = AVG(pricea) FROM artobject2

SELECT A.atitle AS 'Title', m.prices AS 'Price Paid',
CASE WHEN (m.Prices > @AveragePrice)
     THEN 'Higher than average' 
     WHEN (m.Prices < @AveragePrice)
     THEN 'Lower than average' 
     ELSE 'At Average'
   END AS 'Remarks'
FROM MakesD2 M
INNER JOIN ArtObject2 A ON A.aoid = M.aoid;
```

**Explanation of #3 Sql** Store the Average Price in a variable, and then use it in a CASE switch statement to figure out if sale price was above or below average.

Comment: M.cid should be not null I believe.

Comment: @Gayathri No. M.cid not null records will be those customers that have purchased art over 500,000. So negating that will give customers who have not bought over 500,000.

Answer (score 0):

SQL query for #3 (MySQL):

```
SELECT @AVGPRICE := AVG(pricea) FROM artobject2;

SELECT a.atitle,
       m.prices,
       IF (a.pricea > @AVGPRICE, 'Higher than average', 'Lower than average') AS Remark
FROM artobject2 AS a JOIN makesd2 AS m USING (aoid);
```

First you calculate the average price from `artobject2` and save it in a local variable.

I'm not too sure this is what you want, though. Maybe you'd better supply some test data. For example:

```
001 Drinker, by Teomondo Scrofalo
002 La Gioconda, by Leonardo da Vinci

001 250
001 300
001 350
002 1000000000
002 1200000000
002 1400000000
```

The "average price" from the bids table is somewhere around 500,000,000 EUR. So painting 001 will *always* be below average and painting 002 will *always* be above average.

A different approach and different results:

```
SELECT a.atitle,
       m.prices,
       IF (a.pricea > averag, 'Higher than average', 'Lower than average') AS Remark
FROM artobject2 AS a JOIN makesd2 AS m USING (aoid)
JOIN (SELECT aoid, AVG(pricea) AS averag GROUP BY aoid) AS averages USING (aoid);
```

Now the inner table would yield

```
001 300
002 1200000000
```

and you would get

```
001 250 Lower
001 300 Lower -- Note: this is because "equal" is considered "lower"
001 350 Higher
002 1000000000 Lower
002 1200000000 Lower
002 1400000000 Higher
```

You can even complicate things:

```
SELECT a.atitle,
       m.prices,
       CASE
           WHEN a.pricea < averag*0.95 THEN 'Lower than average'
           WHEN a.pricea > averag/0.95 THEN 'Higher than average'
           ELSE CONCAT('About average of ', averag)
       END AS Remark
FROM artobject2 AS a JOIN makesd2 AS m USING (aoid)
JOIN (SELECT aoid, AVG(pricea) AS averag GROUP BY aoid) AS averages USING (aoid);

001 250        Lower than average
001 300        About average of 300
001 350        Higher than average
002 1000000000 Lower than average
002 1200000000 About average of 1200000000
002 1400000000 Higher than average
```